# Using findBy* method on non-primary key UUID type field causes an Exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

This question is related to [a question I had yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918203/marking-uuid-type-field-unique-causes-invaliddataaccessresourceusageexception). They sound like different problems but I just figured out what I think is the core issue. I wasn't sure if redoing that last question is the best course of action here, so I just posted a separate question.

So, back to the issue. I have the following domain class:

```
class Person {

    static constraints = {
        key unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        key sqlType: 'binary(16)'
    }

    UUID key

}
```

Whenever I try to call `findByUserId`, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Cannot query [sample.Person] on non-existent property: key
```

So it turns out, the reason I'm having the issue that I described in the older question is that declaring the property unique implies that during validation, the GORM method `findByUserId` gets called. I discovered this by trying to implement a custom validator that does something similar.

Now my question is, why is this happening, and what can I do about this?

When I use a UUID type identity property (`id`) I don't get any problems with GORM methods `get(id)`, or even `findById(id)`. For example if I have the domain class below:

```
class Person {

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', sqlType: 'binary(16)'
    }

    UUID id

    Person() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID()
    }

}
```

The following tests work just fine:

```
given:
Person person = new Person()
person.save()

expect:
Person.get(person.id)
Person.findById(person.id)
```

Comment: I would try to look at the SQL that being executed.  I'm guessing hibernate is not correctly handling the mapping of the UUID object to a binary column.  You can add `logSql=true` in `DataSource.groovy` to turn on logging.

Comment: I'm not sure about the mapping of UUID to binary column because it works fine if the field is id. I've updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the `type` (either instead of, or in addition to the `sqlType`).  For example, for PostgreSQL it is:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned', type: 'pg-uuid'
}
```

Comment: Is `pg-uuid` vendor specific (I'm getting the impression from the "pg" part)?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- I'll edit my response.  In this case it's what you would use for PostgreSQL.